# How to convert my own python/kivy code from python to apk

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to convert with buildozer but it doesn't work. I also define libraries and file types related to my project in buildozer.spec. what else should i do? Thank you in advance for your help and attention.

Edit: I'm converting this in google colab and this is the situation i came up with with debugging. I don't know what to do next from here. Can you help me please.

These are what i installed

```css
1) !pip install buildozer

2) !pip install cython==0.29.19

3) !lsb_release -a

4) !sudo apt-get install -y \
python3-pip \
build-essential \
git \
python3 \
python3-dev \
ffmpeg \
libsdl2-dev \
libsdl2-image-dev \
libsdl2-mixer-dev \
libsdl2-ttf-dev \
libportmidi-dev \
libswscale-dev \
libavformat-dev \
libavcodec-dev \
zlib1g-dev

5) !sudo apt-get install -y \
libgstreamer1.0 \
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base \
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good

6) !sudo apt-get update
   !sudo apt-get install libtool

7) !sudo apt-get install build-essential libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 bzip2 libbz2-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev openssl libgdbm-dev libgdbm-compat-dev liblzma-dev libreadline-dev libncursesw5-dev libffi-dev uuid-dev libffi6

8) !sudo apt-get install libffi-dev

9) !sudo apt install build-essential autoconf libtool

10) !buildozer init


11) !buildozer -v android debug
```

This is my buildozer.spec file

```css
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Parazit Tespit

# (str) Package name
package.name = parazitsoft

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.parsoft

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,tflite

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,numpy,tensorflow,opencv-python,scipy,jnius

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 2.0.0

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 27

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
android.accept_sdk_license = True

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android fork to use, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.7.0

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

These are also reports

```css
[INFO]:    Detected highest available build tools version to be 31.0.0-rc4
[DEBUG]:   -> running gradlew assembleDebug
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    <-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [83ms]> root project<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [183ms]> root project > Resolve dependencies of :classpath<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [283ms]> root project > Resolve files of :classpath<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [383ms]> root project<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [483ms]<-------------> 2% EXECUTING [583ms]> :preDebugBuild<===----------> 28% EXECUTING [683ms]> :mergeDebugResources<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [783ms]> :processDebugResources<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [884ms]<========-----> 65% EXECUTING [983ms]> :mergeDebugAssets<========-----> 65% EXECUTING [1s]<========-----> 65% EXECUTING [2s]<========-----> 65% EXECUTING [3s]<========-----> 65% EXECUTING [4s]<========-----> 65% EXECUTING [5s]<========-----> 65% EXECUTING [6s]<============-> 94% EXECUTING [7s]> :packageDebug> Task :packageDebug FAILED
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    * What went wrong:
[DEBUG]:    Execution failed for task ':packageDebug'.
[DEBUG]:    > Java heap space
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    * Try:
[DEBUG]:    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
[DEBUG]:    Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
[DEBUG]:    See https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    BUILD FAILED in 8s
[DEBUG]:    27 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 23 up-to-date
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    <-------------> 0% WAITING> IDLE
Exception in thread background thread for pid 42305:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 1683, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 2662, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 2349, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 905, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/parazitsoft__armeabi-v7a/gradlew assembleDebug

  STDOUT:


<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [83ms]> root project<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [183ms]> root project > Resolve dependencies of :classpath<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [283ms]> root project > Resolve files of :classpath<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [383ms]> root project<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [483ms]<-------------> 2% EXECUTING [583ms]> :preDebugBuild<===----------> 28% EXECUTING [683ms]> :mergeDebugResources<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [783ms]> :processDebugResources<=====--------> 40% EXECUTING [884ms]<========-----> 65% EXECUTING [983ms]> :mergeDebugAssets<========-----> 65% EXECUTING [1s]<========-----> 65% EXECUTING [2s]<========-----> 65% EXECUTING [3s]<========-----> 65% EXECUTING [4s]<========-----> 65% EXECUTING [5s]<========-----> 65% EXECUTING [6s]<============-> 94% EXECUTING [7s]> :packageDebug> Task :packageDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':packageDebug'.
> Java heap space

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 8s
27 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 23 up-to-date


<-------------> 0% WAITING> IDLE

  STDERR:


[INFO]:    STDOUT (last 20 lines of 24):
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.    
    
* What went wrong:  
Execution failed for task ':packageDebug'.  
> Java heap space   
    
* Try:  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.    
    
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org  
    
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0. 
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.   
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings   
    
BUILD FAILED in 8s  
27 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 23 up-to-date  
    
    
<-------------> 0% WAITING> IDLE
[INFO]:    STDERR:
    
[INFO]:    COMMAND:
cd /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/parazitsoft__armeabi-v7a && /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/parazitsoft__armeabi-v7a/gradlew assembleDebug

[WARNING]: ERROR: /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/parazitsoft__armeabi-v7a/gradlew failed!
WARNING: Received a --sdk argument, but this argument is deprecated and does nothing.
No setup.py/pyproject.toml used, copying full private data into .apk.
Applying Java source code patches...
Applying patch: src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
Warning: failed to apply patch (exit code 1), assuming it is already applied:  src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain apk --debug --bootstrap=sdl2 --dist_name parazitsoft --name 'Parazit Tespit' --version 0.1 --package org.parsoft.parazitsoft --minsdk 21 --ndk-api 21 --private /content/.buildozer/android/app --android-entrypoint org.kivy.android.PythonActivity --android-apptheme @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar --orientation portrait --window --copy-libs --arch armeabi-v7a --color=always --storage-dir="/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     CUDNN_VERSION = '8.0.4.30'
#     PYDEVD_USE_FRAME_EVAL = 'NO'
#     LD_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64'
#     CLOUDSDK_PYTHON = 'python3'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     HOSTNAME = '3a802bb5857d'
#     OLDPWD = '/'
#     CLOUDSDK_CONFIG = '/content/.config'
#     NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = 'all'
#     DATALAB_SETTINGS_OVERRIDES = '{"kernelManagerProxyPort":6000,"kernelManagerProxyHost":"172.28.0.3","jupyterArgs":["--ip=\\"172.28.0.2\\""],"debugAdapterMultiplexerPath":"/usr/local/bin/dap_multiplexer"}'
#     ENV = '/root/.bashrc'
#     PAGER = 'cat'
#     NCCL_VERSION = '2.7.8'
#     TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH = 'true'
#     JPY_PARENT_PID = '48'
#     NO_GCE_CHECK = 'True'
#     PWD = '/content'
#     HOME = '/root'
#     LAST_FORCED_REBUILD = '20210504'
#     CLICOLOR = '1'
#     DEBIAN_FRONTEND = 'noninteractive'
#     LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs'
#     GCE_METADATA_TIMEOUT = '0'
#     GLIBCPP_FORCE_NEW = '1'
#     TBE_CREDS_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8008'
#     TERM = 'xterm-color'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     GCS_READ_CACHE_BLOCK_SIZE_MB = '16'
#     PYTHONWARNINGS = 'ignore:::pip._internal.cli.base_command'
#     MPLBACKEND = 'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'
#     CUDA_VERSION = '11.0.3'
#     NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES = 'compute,utility'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     PYTHONPATH = '/env/python'
#     NVIDIA_REQUIRE_CUDA = ('cuda>=11.0 brand=tesla,driver>=418,driver<419 '
 'brand=tesla,driver>=440,driver<441 brand=tesla,driver>=450,driver<451')
#     COLAB_GPU = '0'
#     GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW = '1'
#     PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/tools/node/bin:/tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/opt/bin'
#     LD_PRELOAD = '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcmalloc.so.4'
#     GIT_PAGER = 'cat'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: Ask a specific question - you clearly already know that you should use buildozer, if it doesn't work you need to debug whatever particular issue you have.

Answer (score 0):

you need to name your python file "main" and the same with kivy file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).